# How to Convert nvarchar value to data type bit while uploading Excel File

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting an error while uploading an Excel file to the database in C#

Error :

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CiazEC1OA0GtAsa60F1evw' to data type bit

`CiazEC1OA0GtAsa60F1evw`: this is the value of `ConfirmationToken` and `ConfirmationToken` has a `Nvarchar` type in the SQL Server database

Code:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ConfirmationToken", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["ConfirmationToken"]).ToString();
```

Comment: Your database query or schema is wrong. A bit is 0 or 1, you cannot store a string there. Of course you can define rules with which to convert it into 0 or 1, but I assume that's not what you are after? Please also post the SQL query

Comment: To build on what Sami Kuhmonen said, it looks like perhaps you are using a stored procedure. Although, the database table column ConfirmationToken might be NVarchar, maybe there is some conversion happening in the SQL query/procedure that you need to look at.